# Kubernetes on Windows for Production

Tags: windows, kubernetes, containers, production

I just started messing with containers and managing them. Then I came across with Kubernetes. I've already installed Docker and tried out a few examples. But when it came to managing them with Kubernetes, I've kinda stuck.

I've found out that I can run Kubernetes with minikube on Windows on my laptop for development. But I want to know if I can run Kubernetes on my production server or local development environment because as they point out minikube doesn't have all featues that Kubernetes can offer. So in production I guess I can't use minikube, right?

Because of the data that I'm using I can't use Google cloud or Azure for production, laws forbid that. So in short do I have to switch to cloud to use Kubernetes or can I use it in my Windows Server machine without any cloud environment?

I've already read [How to do local development with Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746926/how-to-do-local-development-with-kubernetes) question but they've also recommended minikube.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You can create three node cluster with one master node and other two as pod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So in production I guess I can't use minikube, right?

- Not really advisable, minikube is ment to support learning/local single machine dev tasks.

> do I have to switch to cloud to use Kubernetes or can I use it in my Windows Server machine without any cloud environment?

- IMHO Windows and kubernetes are not really there yet. If you don't want to install dedicated linux box or switch to cloud there is always option to run it from within virtualized environment (VirtualBox, VMWare...). Maybe not super optimal performance-wise (additional layers of virtualization added on top of windows) but can be sufficiently stable for production (depends on available hardware and resources requirements).

Comment: I agree with Const that Windows (Server) is not a good place to plan production installation of Kubernetes. I found this kind of possible installation, and it’s well described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/).

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's seems like running it on Linux host would be better choice in terms of simplicity and performance. Cheers!