# kubectl install - wrong port - config error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am installing kubectl. After installing kubectl I checked for version and got below.

I followed up documentation and checked the config. But it is empty file.

```
Client Version: version.Info{
    Major:"1", 
    Minor:"10", 
    GitVersion:"v1.10.3",                         
    GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", 
    GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z",                         
    GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", 
    Platform:"darwin/amd64"}

   The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`
```

I dont have any local clusters. Is there anything I need to do if I want to connect to EKS Cluster on AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind that is kubectl version prints Client Version and Server Version (kubernetes version) both. When you just install kubectl it is just kubernets client. If you have kubernetes cluster installed, it will print both kubectl version and kubernetes version.

If you want to just want to print client version, then use following command:

```
kubectl version --client=true
```

For details you can check my following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071343/kubernetes-the-connection-to-the-server-localhost8080-was-refused-did-you-s/54071466#54071466)

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I would love to follow up once I get master running soon.

Comment: If you have remote server (kubernetes master) and you want to access that server using kubectl, then you need to copy the kube config file of that server to the node and make sure that the master is accessible from that node

Comment: node you mentioned above would it be kubectl on my local machine if I am to access remote cluster from local?

Comment: Yes node means the local machine from which you want to access the cluster.Here is a nice article to help you understand https://medium.com/@wso2tech/configure-local-kubectl-to-access-remote-kubernetes-cluster-ee78feff2d6d

Comment: Thanks Prafull you are awesome (y)